# Tkinter: Widget not being applied to the top right hand corner of the screen(grid)

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a GUI for a voice assistant and for that when I try to use the grid option the label's get aligned at the centre of the screen when specified as column 2/3/4/5.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Canvas, Frame, Image, Label, StringVar, Tk, font
from tkinter.constants import ANCHOR, BOTTOM, E, END, GROOVE, RAISED, RIDGE, RIGHT, SUNKEN, TOP, Y
from typing import Text
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("App name")
window.geometry("320x640")
f = Frame(window)
x = f.grid_size()
# Add image file
bg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "Greybg.png")
# Show image using label
label1 = tkinter.Label( window, image = bg)
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)

userimg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'user1.png')
userlabel = tkinter.Label(window, image = userimg, bg = '#3D4154')
userlabel.place(relx = 1.0, rely = 0.01, anchor = 'ne')


def clicked():
    print("Wow no error")


# Creating a photoimage object to use image
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "mic.png")
  

# here, image option is used to
# set image on button
micbtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo, bg = '#808588', border = 0, command = clicked).place(x = 142,y=580)


string_variable = tkinter.StringVar()
string_variable.set("User Text Here")
text = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable = string_variable, bg = "#80EAF7", wraplength= 250, pady = 1, padx = 1, fg = '#020402')
text.grid(row = 0, column=1, sticky=E,)


string_variable1 = tkinter.StringVar()
string_variable1.set("Assistant Reply here")
text1 = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable = string_variable1, wraplength= 250, pady = 1, padx = 1, fg = '#020402', font = ('Helvetica',8,'bold'))
text1.grid(row = 1, column=0)

window.resizable(0, 0)
window.mainloop()
```

In the above code, the icons get aligned like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRSlD.png), whereas I want the "User Text Here" to be at the top right-hand corner of the screen, how do I do that?

Comment: You can make column 0 and 1 to use all the horizontal available space using `window.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make columns 0 and 1 to use all the horizontal available space using

```
window.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668

Comment: Firstly, you can mention the user in comments. Then, you can also make it as community wiki ([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/10952503)). Finally don't forget to format the code, specially such as the author's one.